# indent-rainbow extension for vs code highlights red the code with 2 spaces

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentation

I have prettier code formatter installed, which makes 2 spaces as a standard indentation for the code. However, indent-rainbow highlights it as a red, so it thinks that default indentaion is 4 spaces. What do I do?
[here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuLhE.png)

Answer (score 15):

If you installed indent-rainbow, you could remove errors color by adding these to settings.json and reload vscode.

```
"indentRainbow.ignoreErrorLanguages": ["*"],
"indentRainbow.colorOnWhiteSpaceOnly": true,
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to "Change Tab Display Size" and make it 2

press f1 and search for it